# IterItems only looking at first value

Tags: python, dictionary

I  have a simple dictionary in python and I want to iterate over all of the items to print the key and value:

```
 myDictionary = {"0" :0, "1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0, "5":0, "6":12, "7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0, "12":0,"13":12}


 def count(self, myDictionary):
     for k, v in myDictionary.items():
         print k,v
```

Python sees myDictionary as:

```
 {'11': 0, '10': 0, '13': 12, '12': 0, '1': 0, '0': 0, '3': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 0, '7': 0, '6': 12, '9': 0, '8': 0}
```

When the keys and values print out though, only `11 0` print. I also tried iteritems(). Why is only the first element in the dictionary being printed? I have python 2.3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's not relevant to this question, but: Python **2.3**?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Well, I thought different versions had different ways of writing some things. I am using eclipse, and when I started this project, it said that I was using python grammar 2.3.

Comment: The important question is, what does `import sys`; `print(sys.version)` show?  Python 2.3 is a *very* old version of Python (10+ years old).  [And you're right about version information being important sometimes, but it's hard to believe someone's running 2.3.]

Comment: Either give the real code you use, or fix your example. `def count(self, dictionary)` uses different names than the code.

Comment: @DSM yeah I doulee checked. I am using 2.3

Comment: @LearnLanguages96: Now remove the `self` and call the function. You'll see that it works as expected.

Comment: I thought you always had to call "self" with things in python? Or is that just with classes?

Comment: @LearnLanguages96: on the version issue, if that's true, then I recommend upgrading immediately.  2.3 is so old that most answers you read probably won't work for you.

Comment: Well, how would you call the function in this code? The self only makes sense on a class.

Comment: @JochenRitzel had a nice look over python docs again I have a better understanding.

Comment: @DSM just changed over to 3.0 and it works a lot better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the assumption (based on the comments) that this snippet of code does not belong to a dictionary class but is rather a method, so I removed `self` (which is used to call other variables or methods within the class itself) and saw that the following code returned the result you wanted (running python 2.7.3):

```
>>>def count(myDictionary):
        for k,v in myDictionary.items():
            print k,v
>>>count(myDictionary)
11 0
10 0
13 12
12 0
1 0
0 0
3 0
2 0
5 0
4 0
7 0
6 12
9 0
8 0
>>>
```

This supports the need to update to 2.7x and to remove `self` when you call your method with just one dictionary (`myDictionary`) otherwise it will expect two arguments.

If you need the data to be stored in a class structure that can indeed be accomplished but I would only recommend that for a data structure more complicated than the one you posted such as a keyed dictionary where each key has multiple attributes that you would want to call separately. Such as:

`dictionary = {v1: 0, 8, 9, v2: 9,6,3}`

Where `v1`, and `v2` represent 3D vectors with x, y, and z directions which you want to call individually without having to cycle through all of the data.